# Prime Number in an Array

Tags: c++, math

I am trying to loop through an array and count the number of prime numbers in it...Simple enough but I am missing something...

```
count = 0;
for(i =0; i<5; i++)
{
    flag = true;    // is prime
    for (j=2;j<a[i];j++)
    {
        if(a[i] % j == 0)
        {
            flag = false;
        }


    }

    count ++;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code to this

```
flag = true;    // is prime
for (j=2;j<a[i];j++)
{
    if(a[i] % j == 0)
    {
        flag = false;
        break;
    }

}
if (flag) {
   count++;
}
```

Once you have counted a non prime you might as well break out of the loop - it is not going to become unprime again with repeated testing

Comment: If this was an IOCCC entry, I'd suggest it to change into `count += flag;` :P

Comment: You don't need a flag at all: Just advance count and break out of the inner loop.

Comment: @alexis Yes you could simply count++, and break but you would then need to calculate primes from array_length - count. If you want `count` to represent the prime count, you need to check if its still true after the loop. Unless I have totally misunderstood what you mean which is always possible

Comment: oh right, i got the sense of the flag backwards.

Comment: But you could always increment, and in the case of a composite, decrement. Not that that's really better than checking a flag.

Answer (score 5):

You are missing a condition before `count++`.

Answer (score 5):

You increase count even if flag is false.

Answer (score 0):

Blah fixed it with a `(flag == true)` condition before count ++;

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the "if" in line "count++;"

```
count = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    var flag = true;    // is prime
    for (var j = 2; j < a[i]; j++)
    {
        if (a[i] % j == 0)
        {
            flag = false;
            break; //this break will avoid useless process
        }

    }

    // only when the flag is false that the current number is prime.
    if(!flag) count++;
}
```

but a better way to do that is:

```
count = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for (var j = 2; j < a[i]; j++)
    {
        if (a[i] % j == 0)
        {
            count++; // don't need a variable flag, put increment here.
            break;
        }
    }
}
```